# Boolean modifier difference not working as expected

Tags: modifiers

I'm currently modeling a mask to 3d print, and I'm using an extruded svg in order to cut out the eye holes, using the boolean modifier on difference. When I apply the modifier, Blender only adds a 2d version of the svg to my mask, behind where the hole should be. It doesn't actually cut out a hole.

So far I have made sure normals all face the same way, that there are no doubles, and made the object manifold. It's still doing the same thing. I'm also on Blender 2.8, if that helps

What am I doing wrong, and how can I do it properly?

Comment: How you have extruded SVG? If you have done it by extrude property, it creates 3 separate parts. So you have to convert it to mesh, and in edit mode with everything selected, press m - by distance to glue parts together.

Comment: Can you [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your .blend file?